# MIPS assembly instruction to machine code in hex

Tags: assembly, register, binary, mips

I am doing some practice problems involving MIPS assembly instructions and machine code(in hex). I am doing a problem but am uncertain if it is correct. This is the problem, and what I did:

```
addi $8, $9, -150

It is an I-type instruction, so I write it accordingly.

opcode: 001000
rs: 01001
rt: 01000
immediate: 1111111101101010

The answer I came up with is: OX2128FF6A
```

If anyone can check it and let me know if I have done it incorrectly or if you can offer any help/advice, I'd appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Your answer looks ok.

Answer (score 1):

[This handy site](http://www.kurtm.net/mipsasm/index.cgi) agrees with you.